# Is there a matrix norm induced by vector norm for 0<p<1?

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix norm induced by vector norm defined [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) is $||A||_p$ with $p\geq 1$. 
 But how is matrix norm defined for $p<1$ ?

**Edit:**
I am asking this because in the second half of below theorem(in the image), where $r_\sigma (A)$ represents [spectral radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of A, $\epsilon >0$ may be between 0 and 1. How is matrix norm defined then ?

[image]

Comment: The author probably doesn't mean that $\|\cdot\|_\epsilon$ is induced from $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^\epsilon\right)^{1/\epsilon}$. What he/she means are most likely that (a) $\|\cdot\|_\epsilon$ is induced from **some** vector norm, and (b) for the **given** $A$, the inequality (7.3.24) holds. The $\epsilon$ in $\|\cdot\|_\epsilon$ here is just a subscript. It doesn't indicate what vector norm the matrix norm is induced from. I don't know the context of the quoted passage, but it looks like a prelude to [Gelfand's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula).

Answer (score 0):

For vectors $x \in \mathbb{K}^n$ (with $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$) the $p$-Norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ is as well only defined for $p \geq 1$.

The reason is, that for $p<1$ the usual definition $$\lVert x \rVert_p := \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p\right)^{1/p}$$ doesn't result in a norm.

Comment: I have added few more things in question.

Comment: What does matrix norm $||A||_\epsilon$ represent when $0<\epsilon <1$ ?

Comment: Is there given a proof to the theorem?

Comment: No. Not given in that material. Its proof is a nontrivial construction, and a proof of it is given in Isaacson and Keller (1966, p. 12)